# ChartJS 4 migration: access other datasets from tooltip callback

Tags: chart.js

I'm migrating from ChartJS 2.9.3 to 4.2.1 (current). By following the [3.x](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/migration/v3-migration.html) and [4.x](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/migration/v4-migration.html) migration guides, I've sorted most things out, but I've come across a problem that I don't see a solution for.

One of my charts is a stacked bar chart. There are two datasets for it:

```
let chartData = {
    // other stuff...
    datasets: [
        { label: "Has thing", data: [200, 250, etc] },
        { label: "Does not has thing", data: [10, 4, etc] },
    ]
}
```

In my tooltips, I was accessing both datasets to create a custom tooltip with the percent representation of each part of each stack. For instance, the tooltips for the first stack might say: "Has thing: 200 (95.2%)" and "Does not has thing: 10 (4.8%)". My callback function looked like this:

```
// other stuff
callbacks: {
    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        let dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];

        let count_with = data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index]
        let count_without = data.datasets[1].data[tooltipItem.index]
        let total = count_with + count_without

        let this_dataset_count = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index]
        let this_dataset_perc = (this_dataset_count / total * 100).toFixed(1)

        let label = dataset.label + ": "
        label += this_dataset_count + " (" + this_dataset_perc + "%)"
        return label;
    }
}
```

Looking at the 3.x migration guide, it appears they removed the `data` parameter from the tooltip callback, opting instead to add the item's `dataset` directly to the `tooltipItem`. Unfortunately, they don't seem to specify how I can access *other* datasets.

Has this functionality simply been removed completely, or is there a different way to access it?

Comment: You *can* access `data` in `{label: function(context){...}}` as `context.chart.data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @kikon pointed out, `data` is accessible via `context.chart.data`. For some reason, that doesn't show up for me when I `console.dir()` the context object so I was just completely overlooking it.

Anyway, for anyone this might help in the future, here's the working version:

```
callbacks: {
    label: function(context) {
        const datasets = context.chart.data.datasets
        const countWith = datasets[0].data[context.dataIndex]
        const countWithout = datasets[1].data[context.dataIndex]
        const perc = (context.raw / (countWith + countWithout) * 100).toFixed(1)
        return `${context.dataset.label}: ${context.formattedValue} (${perc}%)`
    }
}
```